# Creating New columns from other pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a new **Column** from the genres column.
The genres column contains one or multiple genres and I would like to create a column for each genre name.
Then, I would like to fill in 1 and 0 in each column depending on whether they have the genre.

[image: First Image]

Dataframe should look like in the image below.

[image: Below]

I don't have any clue on this.

Using one hot encoder or pandas dummies function straight away didn't work as I got something like this

[image: Right here]

I don't need something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the values in the `Genre` column were one-hot encoded. One-hot encoding is also know as referred to as creating dummy variables.

Pandas has a function `pd.get_dummies()` that should enable you one-hot encode the `Genre` column. Pass in your data frame and use the `columns` parameter to select the `Genre` column.

See the function documentation and other options here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: It didn't work, It is just creating a column name for every different name occurrence. It creates a column called Action Adventure when it should just put the value one in Action and another in Adventure..Hope you understand my problem in the first instance

Comment: I updated the question, maybe you'll understand me better

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There is another function `str.get_dummies()` that should achieve that by specifying a separator.

Try: `df['Genre'].str.get_dummies(sep = ',')` (replace `df` with the name of your data frame).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CategoricalDtype` as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Brazil', 'Australia', 
'Canada','Brazil','Germany']})

pd.get_dummies(df,prefix=['country'])
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I'll check and give you feedback